# Canvas draws lines too thick

Tags: html, canvas

I want to draw lines on my canvas element at every 48px high. Here's my code (a little jquery selector included since I also use jQuery).

```
var $canvas = $('canvas')
        , maxY = $canvas.outerHeight()
        , maxX = $canvas.outerWidth()
        , X = 0
        , Y = 0
        , ctx = $canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');

    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(100,0,0)";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.0;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    while (Y < maxY) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(X, Y);
        ctx.lineTo(maxX, Y);
        //ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        Y += 48;
    };

    Y = 0;
```

What I experience is that my first line is crisp and 1px high. All my other lines are higher. Here's the result:

[image: result]
<sub>(source: [ghentgators.be](http://ghentgators.be/test/canvas_line_heightnotcorrect.JPG))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your initial `Y` to +0.5 (or -0.5) and you'll get nice lines.